# Redirect and print error without overwrite the file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to save all the errors in a file (`output.log`) WITHOUT overwrite it and then print the file.

`script ./src/ 2>&1 | tee output.log`

Comment: Use the `-a` switch with `tee`.   Your example would become `script ./src/ 2>&1 | tee -a output.log`

Comment: `script` manipulates its output streams.  The whole point of `script` is to save the entire terminal session in a file.  Are you using `script` to be a generic tag to mean any script you are running, or are you actually running the `script` tool?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to append instead of overwriting:

```bash
script ./src/ 2> >(tee -a /tmp/error)
```

This sends only errors to `/tmp/error` as opposed to your proposal, which sends everything to the error file. The `>(command)` mechanism runs the command with `stdin` pointing to the file whose position it is in (in Linux this is accomplished using `/dev/fd/X`).

Assuming you want to abort instead of overwriting:

```bash
set -o noclobber
script ./src/ 2> /tmp/error
```

This will flag an error if `/tmp/error` exists.

If you really do want to capture both `stdout` and `stderr`, use `2>&1` followed by `>` as you proposed.